nm-openvpn errors after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, I'm unable to connect to my OpenVPN connections (via the integrated nm support).
When doing:
cat /var/log/syslog | grep openvpn

I get:
2024-10-09T10:59:06.360831-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <warn>  [1728482346.3607] vpn[0x5cb3f8778d10,86f48d54-9ec2-4e66-816f-2cbd6fe54ab3,"vpn-connection-1"]: starting: failure to start VPN service: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service” (No such file or directory)
2024-10-09T10:59:23.890004-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <info>  [1728482363.8898] vpn[0x5cb3f87512f0,3cb9a354-93d0-42b2-8f79-074b3c827f6f,"vpn-connection-3"]: starting openvpn
2024-10-09T10:59:23.891880-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <warn>  [1728482363.8918] vpn[0x5cb3f87512f0,3cb9a354-93d0-42b2-8f79-074b3c827f6f,"vpn-connection-3"]: starting: failure to start VPN service: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service” (No such file or directory)
2024-10-09T11:07:26.379746-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <info>  [1728482846.3795] vpn[0x5cb3f8778d10,86f48d54-9ec2-4e66-816f-2cbd6fe54ab3,"vpn-connection-1"]: starting openvpn
2024-10-09T11:07:26.383125-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <warn>  [1728482846.3830] vpn[0x5cb3f8778d10,86f48d54-9ec2-4e66-816f-2cbd6fe54ab3,"vpn-connection-1"]: starting: failure to start VPN service: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service” (No such file or directory)
2024-10-09T11:07:45.472647-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <info>  [1728482865.4724] vpn[0x5cb3f87512f0,3f9bb7f3-5db2-4908-b25b-62f19adcd59a,"vpn-connection-2"]: starting openvpn
2024-10-09T11:07:45.474394-03:00 laptop NetworkManager[114597]: <warn>  [1728482865.4743] vpn[0x5cb3f87512f0,3f9bb7f3-5db2-4908-b25b-62f19adcd59a,"vpn-connection-2"]: starting: failure to start VPN service: Failed to execute child process “/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service” (No such file or directory)

And when checking for this file: /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openvpn-service, it doesn't exist.
Any clues?
Thanks!
Mario
